# Write rows to a CSV file if a cell contains a particular string value

Tags: python

I would like to select rows from a CSV file if it contains a particular string in the cells of a 5th column and write these rows to another CSV file. A sample of the data is given below:

[image: A few rows from the sample data]

I would like to write all the rows that contain the string 'Authentication status for' in column E and write it to another file. This is the code I have but it does not seem to work:

```
RawFile = "input.csv"
CleanedFile = "output.csv"
Keyword = 'Authentication status for'
with open(RawFile) as infile, open(CleanedFile, 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        if Keyword in row[4]:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

This keeps throwing up the error `list index out of range`. How can this be sorted out now?

Comment: Can you `print(row)` after the line `for row in reader` and see what you get? Also, I think where you define `Cleaned file` in line 3 you mean `Cleanedfile`.

Comment: Do you have rows that have fewer than 5 columns? You could check for it: `if len(row) >= 5 and keyword in row[4]: ...`.

Comment: @JackParkinson, yes, I meant CleanedFile. Upon inserting the line print(row), I realized what the error was. The file has some empty cells in the 2nd column. Hence, the index does not go beyond 1 and thus an error is returned. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Yes. That seems to be the error @9000. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way this error would be thrown is if there is a row that only has 4 columns. Check through the data and find it, and/or use a try statement:

```
try:
    if Keyword in row[4]:
        writer.writerow(row)
except:
    continue
```

If you are missing data in a different column, you will likely need to go add some sort of placeholder value.

Comment: Brilliant. It works. Simple solution. I don't know why I didn't think of it. Thanks @Cary Shindell!